# Pivot table for same types of values in different columns

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have this dataset where the same person could be in two different columns and so his/her sales records. Is there any way to see their aggregated sales record by person and country using pivot table?

*MS Excel 2016*

[Dataset sample and the way Pivot table should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIE3f.png)

Comment: Please post tables and data as formatted text. See how to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd better use Data>Get&Transform or Data>From Table/Range (I am not sure name in excel 2016, I am using 365). This is to bring your table to Power Query and transform it.

The key thing here is to Transform>Unpivot Other Columns (out of Country and City columns), values: Person1, Person2, Person1_sales, Person2_sales to 1 column. Next remove "1" and "2" to make that column includes only 2 values: Person and Person_sales. Then Transform>Pivot that column becomes 2 columns: Person and Person_sales:

```
    let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Country", "City"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Added addedName_temp" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "addedName_temp", each [Country]&Text.Middle([Attribute],6,1)),
    #"Replace '1'" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Added addedName_temp","1","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Attribute"}),
    #"Replace '2'" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replace '1'","2","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Attribute"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Replace '2'", List.Distinct(#"Replace '2'"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"addedName_temp"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Table after transformed looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNmtr.png)

Here your result in excel pivot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPIZu.png)

You can still use this query in case you have many pairs of Person and Person_sales. Have fun.